# Python MiniDom not removing elements properly

Tags: python, dom

I'm converting a piece of JS code to Python, and I have been using mini DOM, but certain things aren't working right. They were working find when running in JavaScript. I'm converting because I want consistent changes / order (i.e. where the class attribute is added), as well as so I can use some of Pythons easier features.

My latest issue that I've come across is this:

```
fonts = doc.getElementsByTagName('font')

while(fonts.length > 0):
    # Create a new span
    span = doc.createElement("span")
    # Give it a class name based on the color (colors is a map)
    span.setAttribute("class", colors[fonts[0].getAttribute("color")])

    # Place all the children inside
    while(fonts[0].firstChild):
        span.appendChild(fonts[0].firstChild)
    # end while

    # Replace the <font> with a the <span>
    print(fonts[0].parentNode.toxml())
    fonts[0].parentNode.replaceChild(span, fonts[0])
# end while
```

The problem is that, unlike in JavaScript, the element isn't removed from `fonts` like it should be. Is there a better library I should be using that uses the standard (level 3) DOM rules, or am I going to just have to hack it out if I don't want to use xPath (what all the other DOM parsers seem to use)?

Thanks.

Comment: At the very bottom of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html) you can see that they warn that element collections are not live like in the real DOM. This is not usually a problem because you're not scripting in a browser on a webpage with scripts; you're just manipulating static parsed HTML. For this case and many others, you should be able to achieve your desired effect just by altering your code (e.g., iterate over `fonts` instead of always looking at the first element). Is your question how to do this particular task, or how to get completely "real" DOM behavior?

Comment: @BrenBarn, both. I would love real DOM behavior, but if not, then how to solve this problem. Working in v3.4 if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html) for Python DOM (very bottom of the page) that it doesn't work like a "real" DOM in the sense that collections like you get from `getElementsByTagName` are not "live".  Using `getElementsByTagName` here just returns a static snapshot of the matching elements at that moment.  This isn't usually a problem with Python, because when you're using `xml.dom` you're not working with a live-updating page inside a browser; you're just manipulating a static DOM parsed from a file or string, so you know no other code is messing with the DOM while you aren't looking.

In most cases, you can probably get what you want by changing the structure of your code to reflect this.  For this case, you should be able to accomplish your goal with something like this:

```
fonts = doc.getElementsByTagName('font')

for font in fonts:
    # Create a new span
    span = doc.createElement("span")
    # Give it a class name based on the color (colors is a map)
    span.setAttribute("class", colors[font.getAttribute("color")])

    # Place all the children inside
    while(font.firstChild):
        span.appendChild(font.firstChild)
    # end while

    # Replace the <font> with a the <span>
    font.parentNode.replaceChild(span, font)
```

The idea is that instead of always looking at the first element in `fonts`, you iterate over each one and replace them one at a time.

Because of these differences, if your JavaScript DOM code makes use of these sorts of on-the-fly DOM updates, you won't be able to port it "verbatim" to Python (using the same DOM calls).  However, sometimes doing it in this less dynamic way can be easier, because things change less under your feet.

Comment: I agree that things not moving on me may make it easier, as sometimes it's a pain. Other times, like with my original code, I use it to my advantage. :)